# Is it possible to define a fixed string value that can then be followed by free text in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML/XSD and im currently creating a schema.

```
<xs:element name="description_light">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

In the above example, is it possible to add a restriction (or similar) that fixes a starting string to "bla bla" and then followed by any free text?

The goal is to have a field that always starts with the company name and then followed by free text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a pattern facet. `<xs:pattern value="bla bla.*"/>`

Comment: Thanks Michael ! The pattern facet works, but it wont let me have text after "bla bla" 

`<xs:element name="description_light">
 <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
            <xs:pattern value="Kopenhagen Konsulting*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>`

An example would be "Kopenhagen Konsulting assisted in....." - I want to make sure that Kopenhagen Konsulting is the required starting value fort the string

Comment: You need to end it with `.*` (any character repeated zero or more times), not `g*` (`g` repeated zero or more times). Read up on regular expressions, it's one of those technologies where learning it by trial and error is not a good way forward.